# How to make EditText was exactly vertical?

Tags: android, layout

How to make EditText was exactly vertical ?

Thsi is my ScreenShot http://snag.gy/rJpZ4.jpg

This is my XML layout code 
http://pastebin.com/QRNehrRV

Comment: Use Table layout.
Take this as reference http://forum.codecall.net/topic/70354-tablelayout-programatically/

Comment: Yes Yes, This is http://i1068.photobucket.com/albums/u456/TZ-Ecuador/Edicion%2097/tableLayoutC2.png. as is done? that all was exactly.


With XML in any way? ((

Comment: @Pupkovisk Have you tried with weight concept?

Answer (score 0):

Use `layout_weight` Property 
Try this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="One"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Asdds"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="KKssooasscasfas"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Kasfas"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Table layout. 
Take this as reference [forum.codecall.net/topic/70354-tablelayout-programatically/](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/70354-tablelayout-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    -

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="first_name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="user_dob"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="user_gender"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_patient_detail_values"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="12/22/1978"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="M"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```